# How to plot median value on boxplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this boxplot but it is hard to read what value the value of the green line. How can I plot that value? Or is there another way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do could be just plotting directly from the medians calculated from the dataframe

```
In [204]: df
Out[204]: 
          a         b         c         d
0  0.807540  0.719843  0.291329  0.928670
1  0.449082  0.000000  0.575919  0.299698
2  0.703734  0.626004  0.582303  0.243273
3  0.363013  0.539557  0.000000  0.743613
4  0.185610  0.526161  0.795284  0.929223
5  0.000000  0.323683  0.966577  0.259640
6  0.000000  0.386281  0.000000  0.000000
7  0.500604  0.131910  0.413131  0.936908
8  0.992779  0.672049  0.108021  0.558684
9  0.797385  0.199847  0.329550  0.605690

In [205]: df.boxplot()
Out[205]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x103404d6a0>

In [206]: for s, x, y in zip(df.median().map('{:0.2f}'.format), np.arange(df.shape[0]) + 1, df.median()):
     ...:     plt.text(x, y, s, va='center', ha='center')
```

[image]